# Qgis QNEAT3 Plugin execute error

Tags: qgis, network-analyst, isochrone

I have an problem running Iso-Area as Polygons.

```
*Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users/Ivan.Ivanov/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QNEAT3\algs\IsoAreaAsPolygonsFromPoint.py", line 249, in processAlgorithm
polygon_featurelist = net.calcIsoPolygons(max_dist, interval, output_path)
File "C:\Users/Ivan.Ivanov/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QNEAT3\Qneat3Framework.py", line 470, in calcIsoPolygons
band_in = ds_in.GetRasterBand(1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetRasterBand'
Execution failed after 1.98 seconds*
```

All layers are in the same Projected CRS. Yet it doesn't execute. Did someone have faced this problem before. Im available to give more information if needed to solve the problem, I just dont know what more to give.
[image]